# Best practice of creating Delphi package for different Delphi IDEs

Tags: delphi, projects-and-solutions

I maintain [an open source Delphi Library](https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/dutil). I want to have one minimal project file for all Delphi XE series compilers. **Ideally, I need a tool that will create one project file for XE6, and that will strip all redundant information and create corresponding project files for XE-XE5 automatically.** Is there any smart way to achieve that?

Here is my current project file, which contains much redundant information. For instance, it contains a dummy configuration for Android/iOS etc, but my project is targeting  traditional Windows apps. If I manually remove this information, it will come back when the project changes. Also, I know the value of `DebugInformation` was boolean in XE4, but integer in XE5.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectGuid>{1118D87C-9E72-4D93-9098-E70AD237493A}</ProjectGuid>
        <MainSource>dutil_rtl.dpk</MainSource>
        <ProjectVersion>15.1</ProjectVersion>
        <FrameworkType>None</FrameworkType>
        <Base>True</Base>
        <Config Condition="'$(Config)'==''">Release</Config>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)'==''">Win32</Platform>
        <TargetedPlatforms>3</TargetedPlatforms>
        <AppType>Package</AppType>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Base' or '$(Base)'!=''">
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <Base_Win32>true</Base_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win64' and '$(Base)'=='true') or '$(Base_Win64)'!=''">
        <Base_Win64>true</Base_Win64>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug' or '$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Win32>true</Cfg_1_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win64' and '$(Cfg_1)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_1_Win64)'!=''">
        <Cfg_1_Win64>true</Cfg_1_Win64>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_1</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_1>true</Cfg_1>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Config)'=='Release' or '$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win32' and '$(Cfg_2)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_2_Win32)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2_Win32>true</Cfg_2_Win32>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_2</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="('$(Platform)'=='Win64' and '$(Cfg_2)'=='true') or '$(Cfg_2_Win64)'!=''">
        <Cfg_2_Win64>true</Cfg_2_Win64>
        <CfgParent>Cfg_2</CfgParent>
        <Cfg_2>true</Cfg_2>
        <Base>true</Base>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_Keys>CompanyName=;FileDescription=;FileVersion=1.0.0.0;InternalName=;LegalCopyright=;LegalTrademarks=;OriginalFilename=;ProductName=;ProductVersion=1.0.0.0;Comments=</VerInfo_Keys>
        <VerInfo_Locale>1033</VerInfo_Locale>
        <DCC_DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR>false</DCC_DUPLICATE_CTOR_DTOR>
        <GenPackage>true</GenPackage>
        <GenDll>true</GenDll>
        <RuntimeOnlyPackage>true</RuntimeOnlyPackage>
        <DCC_Namespace>System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <DCC_DcuOutput>..\lib\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_DcuOutput>
        <DCC_ExeOutput>.\$(Platform)\$(Config)</DCC_ExeOutput>
        <DCC_E>false</DCC_E>
        <DCC_N>false</DCC_N>
        <DCC_S>false</DCC_S>
        <DCC_F>false</DCC_F>
        <DCC_K>false</DCC_K>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win32)'!=''">
        <DCC_Namespace>Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Base_Win64)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <DCC_Namespace>Winapi;System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;$(DCC_Namespace)</DCC_Namespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_Optimize>false</DCC_Optimize>
        <DCC_GenerateStackFrames>true</DCC_GenerateStackFrames>
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>true</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win32)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>false</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1_Win64)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2)'!=''">
        <DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>false</DCC_LocalDebugSymbols>
        <DCC_Define>RELEASE;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>0</DCC_SymbolReferenceInfo>
        <DCC_DebugInformation>false</DCC_DebugInformation>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2_Win32)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_2_Win64)'!=''">
        <VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>true</VerInfo_IncludeVerInfo>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DelphiCompile Include="$(MainSource)">
            <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
        </DelphiCompile>
        <DCCReference Include="rtl.dcp"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.core.Exception.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.core.NonRefCountedInterfacedObject.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.io.device.File_.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.io.device.TempFile.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.io.FileVersion.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.MessageWindowThread.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.Platform.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.Process.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.registry.Reader.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.registry.Validation.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.registry.Writer.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.SpecialPath.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.sys.win32.SubclassingWindow.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.arg.Arg.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.arg.Arguments.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.arg.Builder.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.Convert.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.json.Json.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.json.Reader.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.json.Validation.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.Util.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.text.xml.Validation.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.time.Time.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.concurrent.FailSafeThread.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.concurrent.Result.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.concurrent.Timer.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.concurrent.TimerImpl.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.concurrent.TimerQueue.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.container.DynArray.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\src\dutil.util.digest.Crc32.pas"/>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Release">
            <Key>Cfg_2</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Base">
            <Key>Base</Key>
        </BuildConfiguration>
        <BuildConfiguration Include="Debug">
            <Key>Cfg_1</Key>
            <CfgParent>Base</CfgParent>
        </BuildConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <Borland.Personality>Delphi.Personality.12</Borland.Personality>
        <Borland.ProjectType>Package</Borland.ProjectType>
        <BorlandProject>
            <Delphi.Personality>
                <VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">True</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MajorVer">1</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="MinorVer">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Release">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Build">0</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Debug">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="PreRelease">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Special">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Private">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="DLL">False</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="Locale">1033</VersionInfo>
                    <VersionInfo Name="CodePage">1252</VersionInfo>
                </VersionInfo>
                <VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="CompanyName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileDescription"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="FileVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="InternalName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalCopyright"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="LegalTrademarks"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="OriginalFilename"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductName"/>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="ProductVersion">1.0.0.0</VersionInfoKeys>
                    <VersionInfoKeys Name="Comments"/>
                </VersionInfoKeys>
                <Source>
                    <Source Name="MainSource">dutil_rtl.dpk</Source>
                </Source>
                <Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dcloffice2k190.bpl">Microsoft Office 2000 Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                    <Excluded_Packages Name="$(BDSBIN)\dclofficexp190.bpl">Microsoft Office XP Sample Automation Server Wrapper Components</Excluded_Packages>
                </Excluded_Packages>
            </Delphi.Personality>
            <Deployment/>
            <Platforms>
                <Platform value="iOSDevice">False</Platform>
                <Platform value="iOSSimulator">False</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win64">True</Platform>
            </Platforms>
        </BorlandProject>
        <ProjectFileVersion>12</ProjectFileVersion>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <Import Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')" Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets"/>
    <Import Condition="Exists('$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj')" Project="$(APPDATA)\Embarcadero\$(BDSAPPDATABASEDIR)\$(PRODUCTVERSION)\UserTools.proj"/>
</Project>
```

Comment: I you want to stay mentally healthy you should go with a separate folder for each IDE version and use LIBSUFFIX to target the proper version.

Comment: That only applies to the output files.  The project file itself cannot be shared across multiple IDE versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, that's why I recommend "a separate folder for each IDE version".

Comment: The problem is that I do not have all Delphi compilers installed. How to create project files individually?

Comment: Newer IDE versions give you licenses and downloads for most older versions. Install them, such as in VMs.  Or find someone who can make the files for you. It is a task to maintain projects for multiple versions. Or, simply don't distribute DPROJ files. When a DPR/DPK is opened directly, a new DPROJ is created if it does not exist. But then you lose the ability to pre-configure multiple platforms. Some things simply require DPROJ files.

Comment: Even only providing one dpk for every version does not work because of the IFDEF IMPLICITBUILD they introduced (in XE2 I think)

Comment: Ideally you should have a master file and generate the version specific .dproj files from that master. Then you can make a change in the master and have it propagate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you help to share this tool which you use in practice ?

Comment: @SOUser I don't have any such tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A single project file may have worked in the old days when everything was based on DPR/DPK files only, but since DPROJ files were introduced a single project will not work anymore. That is because a DPROJ file contains version info, and in some cases node structures, that are different between IDE releases.  If you opened a DPROJ in a newer IDE and the file contained an older version/structure, the IDE would upgrade the project.  If you then saved the changes to the same file, it would not work in older IDEs anymore.

If you look at any of the major third-party component packages, they maintain different projects for each IDE release, for this reason.  You will need to do the same.

Comment: Oh very sorry to hear that, because it is really unclever to have everything in project file.

Comment: @Remy Agreed. Everyone that does not provide separate dpk/dproj for each supported Version is doing it wrong. I have seen many different open source project and every one that did not do this had one or the other problem. Especially not providing dproj (although they contain some personalized config) is a big mistake imo.

Answer (score 2):

Most commercial packages, like DevExpress, and open source components/packages, like SynEdit and the Jedi libraries, use separate project files on the same source code for each version of the IDE. D7, D2010, DXE2...etc.

This allows the providers to use conditional defines to handle varying versions of the IDE's/Platform so that their code will work for the developers.

You will probably need to do the same in order to avoid complex installation instructions for those using your library.

Also, this is pretty much the standard way it is done and people using your library will probably be looking for the appropriately named project file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I am searching a tool to can convert XE5 project file to XE-XE4 automatically, so that I create project file once, a tool will strip redundant from it and create corresponding project files for other Delphi compilers.

Comment: With most library's adding support for newer compilers as time goes by they typically are only creating the project files occasionally. Unlike your case where you are wanting to go and create compatibility for compilers that are recent, but still in use.

You may have to manually go and create the older project files as a off. You would be best served by creating one for the oldest IDE first then opening in the project in the next newer IDE's saving with a different name and repeating for each IDE you wish to support.